# How to capture the stdout of the Python interpreter inside the Rust program when using the pyo3 crate

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I am using the Rust bindings of the Python interpreter provided by the crate `pyo3`.

I have the following code:

```rust
fn run(script: &str) {
    Python::with_gil(|py| py.run(script, None, None)).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    run("print('abc')");
}
```

I would like everything written to stdout by `script` to be captured and accessible from my Rust program, instead of being written to the actual stdout.

That is, in this example, the program should not actually print `abc`, but it should store it somewhere in memory and hand me over a reference, owned string or something.

Ideally this would work via a callback, handing me over lines of output one-by-one as they are created.